# Atributing a value to a cell - Excel

Tags: excel

=IF(D3="+";I3("test1");I3("test1"))

The cell with the code just says "#REF!"

Its probably a sintax error..

What i want is: If the cell D3 is equal to "+" then the value of the cell I3 must be equal to "test1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible using formulas.

A formula can only alter the cell it is written in, it cannot alter any other cell.

Use of vba would be required to make this type of change.

Answer (score 0):

It's syntax. Remove the () in the True, False components and use commas, not semicolons. Type this formula in Cell I3.

```
=IF(D3="+","test1", "")
```

Comment: That will change the value of the cell where the code is written. And i want it to change the value of another cell.

Comment: If the OP is using a version of Excel in which the semicolon is the default argument separator in functions, not the comma, then it is not true that they should necessarily replace those semicolons with commas.

Comment: @XORLX, I believe that is a Windows or other OS setting and not an Excel setting. The default in Excel is ",". That being said, if the default was changed on the OP's machine, then substitute "," in my example to the appropriate separator.

Comment: @lemario, that's going to require VB.

Comment: @rwking But all non-English European versions of Excel, for example, use that setting, as far as I'm aware, so I wouldn't have thought that the comma was "default" for those systems.